# Chrome Extension - Open Multiple Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm Trying to create a function where I can open Multiple Tabs in Chrome (It's a Extension). I found a function from Google their self, but it won't work with my extension. And I also set tabs as permission in the Manifest.

There's a error appear on the Console everytime:

```
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined at popup.js:29 (anonymous) @ popup.js:29*
```

Its My Code

```
for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
link = 'http://www.something.com/'+cats[i];
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: link
});
```

Comment: Content scripts can access only [a few chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), no chrome.tabs.

Comment: @wOxxOm yh, thx. for the Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for Asking, I found the Answer. The Google Chrome TABS Api is only usable in the Popup.html

Comment: you can run this code from popup.js, but it should be included as `<script>` tag in popup.html